# problem in apple's MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

i have code in my current navigation controller in which one button for that....
but when i click button mailcomposer appears **but current navigation controller and its view disappears and then it works... how can i avoid that disappearance,anyhelp please **......
- (IBAction)clickedMailButton:(id)sender
{

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{
    // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }
    else
    {
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }
}
else
{
    [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
}
```

}

Comment: Erm, what do you mean it disappears? If the mail composer sheet is replacing your current view, that is exactly what's supposed to happen.

And you should provide the displayComposerSheet code too.

Comment: it shows like pushview controller from current view controller when we press mail button.but some times it is not working?

Comment: current view controller disappears and then mail compser opens

Answer (score 1):

Clarify what you mean when you say everything disappears.  The class might be deciding that your device is not set up to send e-mails, so it does
    [self launchMailAppOnDevice];

which closes the running app and launches Mail.app

If you have your email set up on the device, a modal view appears and is dismissed when you click send or cancel, revealing your app again.

Comment: it shows like pushview controller from current view controller when we press mail button.but some times it is not working?